# Updating prestahop product quantity

Tags: database, prestashop

Ive noticed that after quantity UPDATE something wrong. It seems that after update stock in product list stay OLD. If I write manual a new value in product -> quantity it refresh to a good.

This is example: http://prntscr.com/54wjk7 in product list we can see - 3
If I open product quantity i can see: http://prntscr.com/54wk2m - 1 in stock

So this is a problem.

My function to update quantities:

```
function update_database($code,$count){
            $res = mysql_query('SELECT `id_product_attribute`,`id_product` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` WHERE `ean13` = \''.$code.'\' LIMIT 1');
            if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
                                echo " ++. ".$count."<br/>";
                $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);    
                mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `ean13` = \''.$code.'\' ');
                mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `id_product` = \''.$row->id_product.'\' ');
                                $id_product_attribute = $row->id_product_attribute;
                                mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `id_product_attribute` = \''.$id_product_attribute.'\' ');
            }else{
                $res = mysql_query('SELECT `id_product` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` WHERE `ean13` = \''.$code.'\' LIMIT 1');
                if(mysql_num_rows($res)){
                                        echo " +++. ".$count."<br/>";
                                        $row = mysql_fetch_object($res);   
                                        $id_product = $row->id_product;
                                        mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `ean13` = \''.$code.'\' ');
                    mysql_query('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'stock_available` SET `quantity` = \''.$count.'\' WHERE `id_product` = \''.$id_product.'\' ');
                }else{
                                        echo " --.";
                    //echo 'Prekė barkodu:'.$code.' nerasta duomenų bazėje';
                }
            }

            mysql_close($this->db);
        }
```

Im using BAR code to update. Where is my fault? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your PS version but I use

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity($product->id, 0, 10000);
```

Here's the method definition

```
public static function setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity, $id_shop = null)
```

Comment: My version 1.6, but its not a module, its simple PHP file. It reads XML to get all quantiti and upload to my PS 1.6 DB.